# Java PushBackInputStream

Tags: java

**why does it printing ".eq." for single = sign while it should actually print on == sign. See comment down there. do f.read() have anything to do with this?**

```
import java.io.*;
public class FPushBackInputStreamDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String s = "if (a == 4) a = 0;\n";
        byte b[] = s.getBytes();
        ByteArrayInputStream b1 = new ByteArrayInputStream(b);
        PushbackInputStream p = new PushbackInputStream(b1);
        int c;

        while((c=p.read()) != -1)
        {
            switch(c)
        {
            case '=':
                if((c = p.read()) == '=') //here it is checking for single '=' sign then why its printing ".eq." for both '==' signs?
                {
                    System.out.print(".eq.");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.print("<-");
                    p.unread(c);

                }
                break;
                default:
                    System.out.print((char) c);
                    break;
        }
    }
}
```

}

**Output:** 
[image]

Comment: Output is illegible. Don't post illegible pictures and waste everybody's bandwidth when you could just copy/paste a few characters of text.

Comment: Being explanatory is and saving time is more important than just worrying about bandwidth

Answer (score 1):

It prints `.eq.` for a double equal sign.

At the point of that `if` statement, you are inside of a `case` of having already read another `=` just in front.

```
while((c=p.read()) != -1)        // read one character
        {
            switch(c)            // see what it is
        {
            case '=':            //    that was a "="
                if((c = p.read()) == '=')       // read ANOTHER character
```

Note that in the `else` part, you have to push back that second character, because it has not actually been processed yet (you just confirmed that it was not a second `=`).

```
  p.unread(c);
```

Comment: p.unread(c) reset stream to 1 character back from current reading?

Comment: It causes `c` to be read as the next character. In this case: yes, it just rewinds the stream one character (but you could put in completely different data).

Comment: Yes it is correct Thilo.The above code is a good example usage of PushbackInputStream